# IF ELSE condition executed even though condition is never true

Tags: oracle, if-statement, plsql, conditional-statements, sqlplus

This is a simple sql statement used to print 2 different questions based on the choice entered. I notice that both statements are run even though the else or if condition is not true. The output printed is correct but I don't require the substitution variable to prompt user for entry if the statement is not true.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE 
    choice number(2) := '&Please_Enter_Choice';
    question varchar2(50);
BEGIN
    if choice = 1 then
        question := '&Whats_your_name?';
    else
        if choice = 2 then
          question := '&How_old_are_you?';
        end if;
    end if;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(question);
END;
```

Comment: sqlplus prompts for all substitution variables BEFORE the block of code even runs

Comment: I'm not trying to be too snarky here, but if an IF statement executes, then you have done something to make the computer think it's true. You need to figure out what step inadvertently returns the `TRUE` result to your IF statement.

Answer (score 6):

Substitution variables like `&Please_Enter_Choice` are replaced in a preprocessing step that takes p!ace (on the client) before the actual code is run (on the server). Please also keep in mind that support for these variables is a feature of the frontend tool (e.g. sql*plus), while the database does not even know they ever existed. Conclusion: you cannot make interactive PL/SQL scripts like that.